# How do I get code to show only images uploaded by current user? P.s. New to programming

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

The following code displays all users images that is uploaded to the database instead of the current user that is logged in. I've tried to retrieve the user specific uploaded pics with 'userCustomerID

As per the title, how do I get code to show only images uploaded by current user?

```
<div class="row">
<?php

    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT userID, userName, userItemName, userItemPrice, userItemQuantity, userItemDetails, userCustomerID, userPic FROM upload_tbl_users ORDER BY userCustomerID DESC');
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            extract($row);
            ?>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <p class="page-header"><?php echo $userName."&nbsp;/&nbsp;".$userItemName; ?></p>
                <a target="_blank" href="user_images/<?php echo $row['userPic']; ?>" />
                <img src="user_images/<?php echo $row['userPic']; ?>" class="img-rounded" width="250px" height="250px" />
                <p class="page-header">
                <span>
                <a class="btn btn-info" href="editform.php?edit_id=<?php echo $row['userCustomerID']; ?>" title="click for edit" onclick="return confirm('sure to edit ?')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a> 
                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="?delete_id=<?php echo $row['userCustomerID']; ?>" title="click for delete" onclick="return confirm('sure to delete ?')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span> Delete</a>
                </span>
                </p>
            </div>       
            <?php
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="alert alert-warning">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; No Data Found ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

?>
</div>
```

Comment: The code displays all users images that is uploaded to the database instead of the current user that is logged in. I've tried to retrieve the user specific uploaded pics with 'userCustomerID'

Answer (score 0):

Then I guess you have to get the id of logged user and add a WHERE clause in your sql script. Like:

```
SELECT...WHERE logged_user_id=uploaded_user_id
```

uploaded_user_id could be userID or userCustomerID I am not sure which in your case, you decide.